# vertical alignment of paragraphs in separate paragraphs of text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Writing text in two-column format and I would like the lines of text to agree between both columns.  Right now I use 12 point font on both sides, but the equations on one side are larger than on the other.

Is there a way to round to the nearest 12 point?  Or some other plausible solution to bring the lines into place?

[image]

The bottom of the paragraph on the right side is higher than the bottom of the left.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,braket}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.5in+2\tabcolsep}|p{3.5in+2\tabcolsep}|}
\hline
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
$$\hat{\phi}(t)  $$ 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah & 

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
$$  \sum_{n \in I} $$ 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please don't make everyone guess all the packages required to run this, edit the question to be a complete small document.

Comment: Are you asking for a solution that typesets the material on a "grid"?

Comment: after your edit `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`, `! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 ...) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \sum_{n \in \mathbb`  and `! Undefined control sequence.
l.24   \braket`  ??????

Comment: @DavidCarlisle equations simplified

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to make it compilable "out of the box".

Comment: @Mico yes... basically a "grid".  i don't know how to make it work on LaTeX

Comment: You may want to look into the [grid](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grid) package. Be forewarned: Grid typesetting is not easy to achieve in LaTeX.

Comment: @Mico that's what I heard... I would settle for something crude like rounding the bbox for equations to the nearest 12pt.  If that's even possible.

Comment: you presumably don't want to round to 12pt, since your text is on a baseline of 14.5pt, that's what I implemented below.

Answer (score 3):

You can make sure each display is in a box that is a multiple of `\normalbaselineskp` in vertical size, and ensure Tex doesn't add additional space around the box.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,braket}
\begin{document}


\def\[#1\]{\endgraf
{%
\sbox0{$\displaystyle#1$}%
\count0=\dimexpr(\ht0+\dp0)/\normalbaselineskip\relax
\dimen0=\dimexpr\count0\normalbaselineskip+2\normalbaselineskip\relax
\vskip-\prevdepth
\nointerlineskip
\vbox to \dimen0{%
\vss
\vskip\dp\strutbox
\box0
\vskip-\dp\strutbox
\vss
}}}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.5in+2\tabcolsep}|p{3.5in+2\tabcolsep}|}
\hline
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\[\hat{\phi}(t)\] 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah & 

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\[  \sum_{n \in I} \] 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply go the `grid.sty` way. Currently, It has three limitations (as per the [package documentation](http://ctan.asis.io/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/grid/grid.pdf)):

- Enunciations (theorem, lemma etc) were not added in the package.
- Optional argument of floats (positioning of floats) are not currently supported.
- Footnotes are not aligned correctly

But it still can give you much. Here is your example implemented with the `grid.sty` package. Note the use of `\begin{gridenv}` and `\end{gridenv}` around any displayed math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,braket}
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt,baseline=14.5pt]{grid}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.5in+2\tabcolsep}|p{3.5in+2\tabcolsep}|}
\hline
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\begin{gridenv}
$$\hat{\phi}(t)  $$ 
\end{gridenv}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah & 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\begin{gridenv}
$$\sum_{n \in I}$$
\end{gridenv} 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

With the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here I introduce `\threerows{}` which takes a `\displaystyle` math argument and will place it in a stack that is three normal row heights tall.  The only proviso is that the argument not be so large vertically that it extends out below or above the spare lines.

Of course, if it is too large vertically, one could create the comparable `\fiverows`:

```
\def\fiverows#1{%
\par{\centering\Centerstack{\\\\ 
\displaystyle#1\\\\}\par}%
}
```

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,braket}
\def\threerows#1{%
\par{\centering\Centerstack{\\ 
\displaystyle#1\\}\par}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.5in+2\tabcolsep}|p{3.5in+2\tabcolsep}|}
\hline
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\threerows{\hat{\phi}(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum_{n\in Z/mZ} \phi(n)
e \left(\frac{nt}{m}\right)}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah & 

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\threerows{\sum_{n \in I} \ldots}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is the `\fiverows` version:

[image]